# Spring Boot Application is running fine locally as a JAR file, but I'm getting an error when I run it as a Windows Service with WinSW

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, windows-services, executable-jar

I tried to run my Spring Boot Application as a Windows Service using WinSW. But I am getting the error below when I start the Service. This error is'nt occuring when I run the JAR file with the command java -jar dc.jar

I am running it on a 64 bit operating system. The datasource I'm using is a 32 bit ODBC driver. The JRE is also 32 bit. I'm using Java 8 but the JdbcOdbc is hacked into it. I can tell that it reaches the datasource, because it isn't giving any errors about no datasource defined.

Are there any suggestions for this issue?

```
2020-03-18 15:53:46.196  INFO 4984 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-18 15:53:48.008 ERROR 4984 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: General error
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6993) ~[jdbc.jar:na]
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121) ~[jdbc.jar:na]
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3080) ~[jdbc.jar:na]
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323) ~[jdbc.jar:na]
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174) ~[jdbc.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.bl.sp.dc.DCApplication.main(DCApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[dc.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[dc.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[dc.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[dc.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Comment: the service is running with the right(your?) authorization for the ODBC-Datasource?

Comment: When running as a service it is not running as you but a system user.  Does the code depend on anything installed to your personal user?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The code doesn't depend on anything except the datasource and the hacked Java 8 version with jdbcodbc. But I think that this is reachable by the system user right?

Comment: @Turo I have configured the ODBC driver in the ODBC-datasourcemanager (32-bits). I did this in the User-DSN and System-DSN.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen actually now I'm thinking. the datasource is configured to point to the database files. But those files are in a folder on the root of my C: drive. Can this be an issue?

Comment: why don't you try and add your credentials to the service?

Comment: @Turo I'm not using credentials. There is no password only local user

Comment: Still you could try and run the service with this user

Comment: @Turo I tried, but I'm getting an error. Can't start service on local computer. Error 1069: The service did not start because of sign in error

Comment: Argh: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047854/cant-run-a-service-under-an-account-which-has-no-password

Comment: @Turo This worked fine, Thank you so much for the help. I appreciate it!